# javascript clone function breaks with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I found this wonderful clone function for javascript (http://my.opera.com/GreyWyvern/blog/show.dml/1725165), but it breaks with jquery with the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object function [removed] has no method 'replace'

Here's the function:

```
Object.prototype.clone = function() {
    var newObj = (this instanceof Array) ? [] : {};
    for (i in this) 
    {
        if (i == 'clone') continue;

        if (this[i] && typeof this[i] == "object")
            newObj[i] = this[i].clone();
        else 
            newObj[i] = this[i]
    } 
    return newObj;
};
```

What does replace have to do with anything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you extend `Object.prototype`, you're taking a risk. It forces all `for-in` enumeration to add `hasOwnProperty` to ensure the `Object.prototype` extension isn't included.

jQuery doesn't always include that check, presumably because of the performance impact. So somewhere along the line it's coming across your `clone` function in the wrong place.

You'll be better off *not* having it on `Object.prototype`, but rather having it directly on `Object`.

```
Object.clone = function(obj) {
    var newObj = (this instanceof Array) ? [] : {};
    for (i in this)  {

        if (obj[i] && typeof obj[i] == "object")
            newObj[i] = Object.clone(obj[i]);
        else 
            newObj[i] = obj[i]
    } 
    return newObj;
};
```

Then call it from the object...

```
var clone = Object.clone(some_object);
```

---

Notice that the original function had the line...

```
if (i == 'clone') continue;
```

This means that you could never clone a property named `clone`. This is obviously not a good thing.

Comment: I'm not sure i understood what he was saying, but one guy said that the line "if( i == 'clone') continue;" was needed because it'll break the code or something: http://my.opera.com/GreyWyvern/blog/show.dml/1725165#comment4810736

Comment: @LordZardeck: It's needed to overcome the fact that because you have `Object.prototype.clone`, *every* object will hit that `clone` property when enumerating. Without that line, every object you clone will have that `clone` function added directly to it. So during the iteration, you need to test to see if the current property is that `clone` property. Unfortunately, you may have an object someday that has its own `clone` property for other purposes. This property will now be passed over 100% of the time. By removing the function from `Object.prototype`, we no longer need that line.

Comment: ...bottom line is *don't add anything to `Object.prototype`*. It's considered a bad practice for very good reason. The jQuery error is one example.

Comment: one last question: what's the difference between creating Object.clone () and just clone()? Because it works with just clone(), but Object.clone() breaks some random part of my code

Comment: @LordZardeck: Not sure why it would break your code, but it doesn't really matter where you store `clone`. `Object` is a function. But all functions in javascript are objects. This means that you can add properties to functions. So all I did was borrow the `Object` function as a namespace to store the `clone` function. You don't need to do this if you don't want.

Comment: ok. It's weird, and doesn't make sense. But instead of wasting time on what doesn't work, i'll work on what does. Thanks for your insight!